# Running a Angular front-end written in TypeScript in a C# Web API project?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I have an existing ASP.NET Web API project, complete with all the API controllers I need for some service.  Previously when using this API, clients just did their typical URI routing to use this API.

Now, with ASP.NET Web API, they provide a simple front end.  I'd like to add AngularJS to this, and I see one obvious way to do that, and that's through Angular's JavaScript library.  How can one do this with TypeScript?  I understand that TypeScript is a language that compiles down into JavaScript, which to me implies that I need to get some step in the build process for Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) that builds the TypeScript for my front end.

How can this be done?  I have done some [tutorials for TypeScript](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) where they have you pull something off NPM that gives you the foundation for your website and you go from there.  However, in all of these tutorials, I've done this in Visual Studio Code where you have the Angular CLI and you can `ng serve --open` to run the web server and develop your website, but I have no clue how to translate this feature into Visual Studio 2017 where both the Web API and the Angular front end are both running at the same time.

I envision the product I'm working on running on IIS and when clients navigate to the page, they'd be served up the Angular front end and the Web API would exist in the back end doing what it does, but I don't know how to marry these two together.  Do you need to have two web servers running, one for the Web API and the other for the front end?  If you can do it on a single web server, how can it be done?  Thanks.

Comment: You don't marry them. That's *exactly* the point of having different applications. What you need it's an angular tutorial which is off-topic for this site. Just follow the official tutorials and you'll be ok. Otherwise, use the ASP.NET Core 2 Angular template which is provided by Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working API you can run this as normal, say on localhost:8000.

Now you create your SPA (angular or whatever) and run that on localhost:8001.

They run independently, all you do is query your endpoints, obviously passing paramters (say localhost:8000/api/something/3) in order to retrieve the data you're looking for.

If the API is not public, you simply don't expose it as such.